# How can I add third-party JavaScript libraries to a Meteor application?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I want to add a JavaScript front-end plugin, like `jquery.center.js`, to a Meteor app.

If I put it in my `app/` directory and refresh the page I get this error:

> Your app is crashing. Here's the latest log.
>
> node.js:201
>   throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
>                 ^
>   ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
>   at app/jquery.center.js:43:1
>   at /Users/crapthings/Desktop/app/.meteor/local/build/server/server.js:111:21
>   at Array.forEach (native)
>   at Function. (/Users/crapthings/Desktop/app/.meteor/local/build/server/underscore.js:76:11)
>   at /Users/crapthings/Desktop/app/.meteor/local/build/server/server.js:97:7
>   Exited with code: 1
>   Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.

Comment: [Things (and the correct answer) have changed quite radically since Meteor v1.3.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11009971/how-can-i-add-third-party-javascript-libraries-to-a-meteor-application/27182267#27182267)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You are putting jquery plugin javascript file in app folder directly,so that javascript file will be be loaded for client as well as server.

**As per Meteor documentation:**
Client loads javascript from: project/public and project/client
Server loads javascript from: project/public and project/server folders.

As of v1.0, Meteor is using jQuery internally in the client, so you can use your library directly without adding jQuery. However, it's recommended that you add jQuery to your Meteor project explicitly:

> meteor add  jquery

The Meteor docs explain in depth [how JavaScript files are loaded and where static assets should go](https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html) (CSS, images).

See also **[how to repackage an existing library for Meteor](https://github.com/raix/Meteor-community-discussions/issues/14)**.

Comment: What about the assets (css, images, ...)? Where you put them?

Comment: Css and images should be put into the "public" directory at the root of your project. More: [Where should I put my files?](https://github.com/oortcloud/unofficial-meteor-faq#where-should-i-put-my-files)

Answer (score 19):

Put it inside the `client` folder such that it is only loaded on the client, no need for jQuery on server.

Answer (score 13):

One way to do this in MeterorJS 1.3.x

Add the JS files in the `public\js\` directory

[image]

Load it up from Meteor.startup method using $.getScript in client/main.js
If you want to control script load sequence, control with multiple $.getScript for each js files.

[image]

```
Meteor.startup(function(){
    $.getScript('js/fhir-client.js', function(){
        // script should be loaded and do something with it. 

    });
});
```

Comment: If the 3rd party library is on npm, it's best to [add it from npm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11009971/how-can-i-add-third-party-javascript-libraries-to-a-meteor-application/27182267#27182267).

Answer (score 3):

Starting with Meteor 1.3, you can [add 3rd party JavaScript libraries to a Meteor project directly via their npm package](https://guide.meteor.com/using-npm-packages.html):

```
meteor npm install --save moment
```

Both server-side and client-side package work without modification because Meteor's ES2015 module system takes care of creating a Node-like environment in the client much as browserify or webpack do.

If an npm package happens to not function correctly, look for a wrapper on [Atmoshpere](http://atmospherejs.com/). Atmosphere is Meteor's official 3rd package repository, but less and less relevant after Meteor v1.3. It will eventuall be [phased out](https://guide.meteor.com/atmosphere-vs-npm.html).

#### History

Before Meteor 1.3, you had to [repackage 3rd party libraries for Meteor](https://github.com/raix/Meteor-community-discussions/issues/14). A tool called Autopublish was developed to automate the process. After the Meteor Development Group stopped offering free hosting at meteor.com, Autopublish was discontinued.