# Why isn't a 3rd party JavaScript library rendered in Meteor?

Tags: meteor, dropzone.js, filepicker.io

I've just recently started using [meteor](/questions/tagged/meteor).

I can't seem to wrap my head around how to properly load and [use 3rd party JavaScript libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11009971/how-can-i-add-third-party-javascript-libraries-to-a-meteor-application).

I am trying to implement a file upload form with the help of some 3rd parties. I want something like DropzoneJS or [jQuery Multiple File Upload](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/) to handle file selection, while [Ink File Picker](https://developers.inkfilepicker.com/docs/web/) stores the files in the cloud.

The problem is that the libraries don't react when I try to use them. I can see in the browser that the library gets loaded, and the console is not showing any errors.

**Example with DropzoneJS:**

**JS:**

```
Template.frontpage.rendered = function () {
  $('#dropzone').dropzone({ url: '/file/post' });
}
```

**HTML in the frontpage template:**

```
<form id="dropzone"></form>
```

**This results when inspecting:**

```
<form id="dropzone" class="MultiFile-intercepted dz-clickable"></form>
```

Something is happening, but the form is not being visually rendered at all.

I place the libs in the /client/libs directory. As some have suggested, I've also tried placing them in /client/compatibility.

I have also tried the [Dropzonejs meteorite package](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/Dropzonejs) with no difference.

What am I doing wrong? How can I make libraries like these function properly in Meteor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do it is to create smart package and include them in your app.

http://docs.meteor.com/#writingpackages

There are plenty of package examples to follow.

https://atmosphere.meteor.com/

For quick hack, you can also load javascript by creating  tag in main.html or call $.getScript(). But this is not recommended as some libraries will have namespace/name conflicts with each other.

Answer (score 0):

Some 3rd party libraries may work out of the box with Meteor, while others may not.

If you actually have an issue with the [Dropzonejs meteorite package](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/Dropzonejs), then you should file a bug on its GitHub, because meteorie package should work.

For other 3rd party libraries, the issue is usually one of scoping. Check out **[Packaging Existing Libraries for Meteor](https://github.com/awwx/misc/wiki/Packaging-Existing-Libraries-for-Meteor)** for suggestions. Usually what's required are some export statements.