# Where to add jQuery scripts in a Meteor application

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

where would I add jQuery script tags for templates? I get an error if I add them to the template.js page. For example, where would i go about adding a mouseover function?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I add third-party JavaScript libraries to a Meteor application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11009971/how-can-i-add-third-party-javascript-libraries-to-a-meteor-application)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add client-side, place it in project_name/public

To add plugin, run

```
Meteor add jquery
```

For further information checkout this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11027228/2308005)

Comment: When you see such a closely related question, the best thing is to flag as duplicate if your answer does not have much to add to the issue.

Comment: In the duplication, they talk about third party libraries, not jquery(indeed jquery is available internally) and dup answer says that jquery is available by default, so considered this is not that much duplication, I would agree with you if the question was about jquery-ui or something else

Answer (score 2):

The 'meteor' place to attach events is in `Template.myTemplate.events`  ([docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_events)) but you can also run arbitrary jQuery in `Template.myTemplate.onRendered = function(){ //code here}`. ([docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_onRendered)) 
These can go in the template's js file.

If you haven't removed jQuery, you don't need to add it, it's there by default.

Generally you don't need to add script tags anywhere.