# Adding a 3rd party library to Meteor project

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I want to add scrollto plugin to my Meteor project

I created package.js like in this tutorial: [enter link description here](http://angular-meteor.com/tutorials/angular1/3rd-party-libraries)

http://codeshare.io/SeCCt

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: BTW, This question has been already asked several times, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11009971/how-can-i-add-third-party-javascript-libraries-to-a-meteor-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to create package for that. It's enough if you put the plugin file inside `/client/lib/` directory. Please not that in order for your plugin to work, the `jquery` built-in package must be added to your application, but it should be already there by default.

However, if you really want to create a package for that (sometimes it's useful) you will need to put the plugin source code (e.g. `jquery.scrollTo.js`) along with the `package.js` file in a separated subdirectory inside `packages/` in your project root. Directory structure should look like this:

```
.meteor/
client/
packages/
  jquery-scrollto/
    package.js
    jquery.scrollTo.js
```

and the source of `package.js`:

```
Package.describe({
  summary: "A jquery.scrollTo plugin",
  version: "1.2.3", // best to use the version of plugin
  name: "jquery-scrollto",
});

Package.onUse(function (api) {
  api.versionsFrom("METEOR@1.0");
  api.use('jquery', 'client');
  api.addFiles('jquery.scrollTo.js', 'client');
});
```

Finally add your package name - so `jquery-scrollto` - to the list in `.meteor/packages` file.

Comment: Thanks for answer, corect me if i am wrong. Command meteor publish --create should be add package to .meteor/packages but i get this message

The package you are in appears to be inside a Meteor app but is not in its packages directory. You may only publish packages that are entirely outside of a project or that are loaded by the project that they are inside.

Comment: Nope. What you want is probably "meteor add my-package-name".

Comment: If you only want to use this package in your project there's now need to publish it. It's enough if it stays in the "packages" subdirectory. Publishing would put your package on the "atmosphere" and make it available to everyone.

Comment: Ok, so this is my directory structure

http://codeshare.io/0STeb
And packages in .meteor looks this 

http://codeshare.io/xeSRq

But i getting error
   "While selecting package versions:
   error: unknown package in top-level dependencies: jquery-scrollto"

Comment: In "packages" you need to create another directory e.g. "jquery-scrollto" (but the name of the directory does not matter) and put your "package.js" inside that directory.

Comment: Oh now i see, but i have one more problem. I get error While selecting package versions:
   error: unknown package: jquery:jquery
   Required by: jquery-scrollto 2.1.1 And i don't know what i am setting wrong. In bower.json was "jquery": ">=1.8" so i set api.use('jquery:jquery@1.11.3', where);

Comment: I think it's just "jquery" and not "jquery:jquery". It's a built-in package.

Comment: I change like you said and now i get    While building package jquery-scrollto:
   error: File not found: src/jquery.scrollTo.js
It is very confused for me. I add new subdirectory src and put my js file jquery.scrollTo.js but nothing happend. They should not automatically download this file?

Comment: No, they don't do it. Meteor depends on you to provide all necessary source code.

Comment: So, wher should i put my js file? Now i have /src/jquery.scrollTo.js maybe i will move to .metor? I don't know...

Comment: I change name of file from jquery.scrollTo.js on just scrollTo.js but stil doesn't not found

Comment: I updated the answer and I described a more simple solution as well. You should figure it out on your own from this point.

Comment: Wow Amazing now is working :) I tryied both solution and both working thanks very much for help