# Meteor AngularJS adding external js libraries

Tags: meteor

I am a little new to angular-meteor and want to add an external js library to my project.
The library is Fusioncharts.js http://www.fusioncharts.com/angularjs-charts/#/demos/ex1 and it cannot be installed using any of these options
1) bower install
2) npm install
3) meteor add (from atmosphere)

So what i did is, I followed these steps [How can I add third-party JavaScript libraries to a Meteor application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11009971/how-can-i-add-third-party-javascript-libraries-to-a-meteor-application)
and added the libraries manually under public/js directory
Created a main.js file and added all the scripts using $.getScript

Strange thing is when I add the dependency of the 'ng-fusioncharts' module in my angular.module it throws an error
" Module 'ng-fusioncharts' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it."

Please let me know what could be going wrong here.
P.S : When I type in FusionCharts in the console.log I do see that object.
So it means the Fusioncharts libraries were imported properly but not added to the angular dependency
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Please note that `$.getScript` is asynchronous, so you would need a little timeout to wait for the module to be available to the rest of your code.

Another possibility to try out would be to include your script rather in `client/compatibility` [special folder](https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#special-directories). It will be included in your JS and execute before the rest of your client JS code.

Comment: I am glad it worked for you. Thank you for the feedback. Please note that the SO way to thank people is also to **accept** the answer that helped you. Once you have enough "reputation", you will also have the ability to "up vote".

Comment: Should I be doing the same thing for adding external ".css" files ?